# Inspecting data descriptor attributes in python

Tags: python

I'm attempting to use a data descriptor to provide some custom get/set functionality to attributes of a class. I'd like to be able to inspect the class at runtime and get a list of data descriptors on that class, and maybe even determine what the type of the descriptor is.

The problem is that when I look at the members I get using `inspect.getmembers` my data descriptor attributes are resolved (their `__get__` method is already called and that result is set as the value of the object).

I'm using the example from: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html

```
import inspect

class RevealAccess(object):
    """A data descriptor that sets and returns values
       normally and prints a message logging their access.
    """

    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print 'Retrieving', self.name
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print 'Updating', self.name
        self.val = val


class MyClass(object):
    x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')
    y = 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in inspect.getmembers(MyClass, inspect.isdatadescriptor):
        print x
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Retrieving var "x"
('__weakref__', <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>)
```

What I *expect* is more like:

```
('x', <attribute 'x' of 'MyClass' objects>)
('__weakref__', <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>)
```

I know I'm missing something I just can't put my finger on it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the descriptor itself, you can look into class `__dict__`:

```
MyClass.__dict__['x']
```

But the better way is to modify the getter:

```
def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
    print 'Retrieving', self.name
    if obj is None:  # accessed as class attribute
        return self  # return the descriptor itself
    else:  # accessed as instance attribute
        return self.val  # return a value
```

Which gives:

```
Retrieving var "x"
('__weakref__', <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>)
('x', <__main__.RevealAccess object at 0x7f32ef989890>)
```